# Training Neural Networks with large data: Howto?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm doing a cloud recognition of satellite scanned data by using TensorFlow, but I found that the amount of data is so large that the memory of my computer is not enough to store all the sample data, the data is stored in many `.npy` format files,  512*512 with 9 channels. I want to ask whether there is any way to get the `batch_size` data for training directly. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can use `tf.data.Dataset` to input large datasets to models.

Comment: thanks for advice ! I use tf.data.Dataset , but I find there is no way to open .npy file with tensorflow ,I can not use np.load cause this API expected str, not Tensor, and I want to ask if there is any way to open .npy file with tensorflow or transform tensor to string,